# cudnn compile configuration in TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow, cudnn

Ubuntu 14.04, CUDA Version 7.5.18, nightly build of tensorflow

While running a `tf.nn.max_pool()` operation in tensorflow, I got the following error:

> E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:286] Loaded cudnn
>   library: 5005 but source was compiled against 4007.  If using a binary
>   install, upgrade your cudnn library to match.  If building from
>   sources, make sure the library loaded matches the version you
>   specified during compile configuration.
>
> W tensorflow/stream_executor/stream.cc:577] attempting to perform DNN
>   operation using StreamExecutor without DNN support
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> ...

How do I specify my cudnn version in the compile configuration of tensorflow?

Comment: I'm confused what this error even means, does it mean that you have a version of cudnn but tensorflow expected a different one or what does it mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go in the directory of TensorFlow source code, then execute the configuration file: `/.configure`.

Here is an example from the [TensorFlow documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/get_started/os_setup.html#installation-for-linux):

```
$ ./configure
Please specify the location of python. [Default is /usr/bin/python]:
Do you wish to build TensorFlow with GPU support? [y/N] y
GPU support will be enabled for TensorFlow

Please specify which gcc nvcc should use as the host compiler. [Default is
/usr/bin/gcc]: /usr/bin/gcc-4.9

Please specify the Cuda SDK version you want to use, e.g. 7.0. [Leave
empty to use system default]: 7.5

Please specify the location where CUDA 7.5 toolkit is installed. Refer to
README.md for more details. [default is: /usr/local/cuda]: /usr/local/cuda

Please specify the Cudnn version you want to use. [Leave empty to use system
default]: 4.0.4

Please specify the location where the cuDNN 4.0.4 library is installed. Refer to
README.md for more details. [default is: /usr/local/cuda]: /usr/local/cudnn-r4-rc/

Please specify a list of comma-separated Cuda compute capabilities you want to
build with. You can find the compute capability of your device at:
https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-gpus.
Please note that each additional compute capability significantly increases your
build time and binary size. [Default is: \"3.5,5.2\"]: 3.5

Setting up Cuda include
Setting up Cuda lib64
Setting up Cuda bin
Setting up Cuda nvvm
Setting up CUPTI include
Setting up CUPTI lib64
Configuration finished
```

Comment: So there is no way around having to recompile tensorflow yourself with bazel, in order to change the cudnn version? I cannot configure my current installation?

Comment: When running `./configure`, you will have to recompile with bazel. Maybe there is another way I am not aware of !

Comment: One question: how to solve if the installation is from binary ?

Comment: "If using a binary install, upgrade your cudnn library to match"

Comment: If one installs it with pip, what is the solution to this problem? Is it the same?

Comment: Yes, pip install is the same as binary. You need to have the standard cudnn version

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you have cudnn 5 installed. You need to set it when running `./configure`

```
Please specify the Cudnn version you want to use. [Leave empty to use system
default]: 5
```

Comment: Can I run `./configure` in a current implementation, or do I need to recompile with Bazel?

Comment: @GunnarNielsen You need to recompile from the source code

Comment: If one installs it with pip, what is the solution to this problem? Is it the same?

Answer (score 1):

Adding my 2 cents: In my case (TF0.12.1, installed to anaconda from `pip`, without `sudo` permissions) CuDNNv5 was installed, but was not the default.

setting `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/lib/cuda-8.0/lib64:/usr/local/lib/cudann5/lib64/"` solved the issue

Answer (score 0):

I also meet this incompatible problem like this :

```
Loaded runtime CuDNN library: 5005 (compatibility version 5000) but source wascompiled with 5110 (compatibility version 5100).  If using a binary install, upgrade your CuDNNlibrary to match.  If building fromsources, make sure the library loaded at runtime matches a compatible versionspecified during compile configuration.
```

So i download CuDNN 5.1(compatible with CUDA8.0) and replace 5.0 with it then everything goes well.

WARN : [CuDNN](https://developer.nvidia.com/cudnn) from nvidia is unavaliable,but you can find it from other's share.